# In Spring boot TypeMismatchException.getPropertyName() is always returning null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, type-mismatch, exceptionhandler

In my Spring boot application, I have controller method with RequestParam Integer clockDrift. When testing it from Postman, if i provide integer value, everything is working as expected. But if I provide any string value in clockDrift field, the request is send to the handleTypeMismatch method in handler class. I am trying to get the property name from TypeMismatchException ex. I am always getting null. Via Eclipse if I inspect ex, I am able to see 'clockDrift' under name (I see F symbol near to that. Not sure what is that. I would appreciate if you could explain the significance of F). But not sure how to get the value of name. I don't see any method other than getPropertyName(). How to get the property name from TypeMismatchException  object?

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApiGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
..
..
  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleTypeMismatch(TypeMismatchException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status,
      WebRequest request)
  {
    System.out.println(ex.getPropertyName()); -- Returning null
    String message = "Input value '" + ex.getValue() + "'" + " is  invalid. Required type is "
        + ex.getRequiredType().getSimpleName();

    return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(SecurityTransformationUtil.buildServiceMessageResponse(status, message));
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I wonder if it might be possible to get the name by calling [`ex.getPropertyChangeEvent().getPropertyName()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/PropertyAccessException.html#getPropertyChangeEvent--)

Comment: According to the javadoc property name is not populated if initPropertyName was not ever called. Likely whatever you have creating this exception doesn't do it.

Comment: @IronMan ex.getPropertyChangeEvent().getPropertyName();
 Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
  java.lang.NullPointerException at getPropertyName()